# Compiling phpredis for windows

Tags: php, visual-studio, apache, redis

I am trying to find phpredis extension (php) for my development server, I know how to build it on linux but I'm not sure how to achieve that on windows, I have tried the one available on internet but that is VC9 version while my php is compiled with VC6, anybody have VC6 version or know how to compile that on windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get VC6 binary here:

https://github.com/owlient/phpredis/issues/87

Answer (score 5):

Both VC6 and VC9 versions:
https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/downloads